# Retrieving usable text between tags from Google Place API via python

Tags: python, json, google-api

I'm trying to collect certain info by retreiving JSON from a url and then running it through beautiful soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import googlemaps

placeDetailsResult = 
urllib.request.urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/
json? 
placeid=ChIJXSggtzAF1h0RXd_aMn0d16Q&cr=countryZA&lr=lang_en&key='+googleKey)
.read()
info = json.loads(placeDetailsResult.decode('utf-8'))
ghtml = info.content
gsoup = soup(ghtml, "lxml")
rawFormattedAddress = gsoup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 
'Formatted_Address'})
print(rawFormattedAddress)
```

I'm getting :

> ghtml = info.content AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'

I've been encoding and decoding trying to sort out problem after problem, Is there an easier way to retrieve tag info from the google api result? Am I doing something horrendous?

Comment: change `ghtml = info.content` to `ghtml = info`.. what do you get?

Comment: BeautifulSoup is intended to parse html/xml. Why not just get the data you need from the `info` dictionary?